# Box with incoming and outgoing arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to make figure using TikZ but couldn't seem to achieve the desired result.
I need to make a box with some incoming arrows and some with outgoing arrows.

My minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    %
    \tikzstyle{int}=[draw, fill=blue!20, minimum size=7em]
    \tikzstyle{init} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm,auto,>=latex']
    \node [int] (a) {$U$ \vspace{1cm} evolution operator};
    \node (b) [left of=a,node distance=3cm, coordinate] {a1};
    \node (c) [right of=a,node distance=3cm, coordinate] {b1};
    \node (d) [left of=a,node distance=3cm, coordinate] {a2};
    \node (e) [right of=a,node distance=3cm, coordinate] {b2};
    \path[->] (b) edge node {$a1$} (a);
    \path[<-] (c) edge node {$b1$} (a);
    \path[->] (d) edge node {$a2$} (a);
    \path[<-] (e) edge node {$b2$} (a);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The problem I have encountered is that I thought a1 and a2 will be the separated by some vertical distance but they got merged, similarly b1 and b2.

Is there a way I can separate them, and make a figure with a1, a2, a3 incoming arrows and b1, b2 and b3 with outgoing arrows

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you want it to look, but you appear to be drawing arrows between the same points. That is, nodes`(b)` and `(d)` are at the same location as are nodes `(c)` and `(e)`. If you want the arrows (and the labels) to be in different locations, then you need to change the start and end nodes.

Comment: @TH. Ya I am missing that. How can I do that?

Comment: Shamina, AboAmmar provided a good answer for one way to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only change the last four lines so that the arrows start relative to `a.west` and `a.east`, you can achieve want you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    %
    \tikzstyle{int}=[draw, fill=blue!20, minimum size=7em]
    \tikzstyle{init} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm,auto,>=latex']
    \node [int,align=center] (a) {$U$\\evolution operator};    
    \draw[<-] ([yshift=5pt]a.west)  -- node[above]{$a1$} ++(-4em,0em);
    \draw[<-] ([yshift=-5pt]a.west) -- node[below]{$a2$} ++(-4em,0em);
    \draw[->] ([yshift=5pt]a.east)  -- node[above]{$b1$} ++(4em,0em);
    \draw[->] ([yshift=-5pt]a.east) -- node[below]{$b2$} ++(4em,0em);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

This solved the problem, after working around I got the solution. Thanks to you all people

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw,minimum height=3cm] (a) {$U$ \vspace{1cm} evolution operator};
\path (a.south east) -- (a.north east)
      coordinate [pos=0.2] (p1)
      coordinate [pos=0.5] (p2)      
      coordinate [pos=0.8] (p3);
\path (a.south west) -- (a.north west)
      coordinate [pos=0.2] (p4)
      coordinate [pos=0.5] (p5)      
      coordinate [pos=0.8] (p6);
\draw [->] (p1) -- +(1cm,0) node[right]{$b_1$};
\draw [->] (p2) -- +(1cm,0) node[right]{$b_2$};
\draw [->] (p3) -- +(1cm,0) node[right]{$b_3$};
\draw [<-] (p4) -- +(-1cm,0) node[left]{$a_1$};
\draw [<-] (p5) -- +(-1cm,0) node[left]{$a_2$};
\draw [<-] (p6) -- +(-1cm,0) node[left]{$a_3$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```